# State not saved after change language in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have implement app in which i have change language after click on list item and it is changed but after kill app the state of language not saved..... though i have save it to sharedpreference....

Here is my code:

```
public class Languages extends Fragment {
// private int current = -1;
View view;
Context ct;
SharedPreferences sp1, sp;
Boolean Ischeck = false;
String User_id, countryid;
Button settings;
// String[] arrLanguages = new String[]{"English", "Arabic"};
String[] arrLanguages = new String[] { "English", "Arabic" };
String req, locale;
ListView lv;
private Locale myLocale;

public Languages(Context c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.ct = c;
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.languagechange, container, false);
    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
    User_id = sp.getString("userid=", User_id);
    countryid = sp.getString("countryid", countryid);
    settings = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnsett);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(ct, arrLanguages));
    settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.popBackStack();
            Log.d("Back to Home", "back button pressed");
        }
    });
    loadLocale();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // get selected items
            String selectedValue = (String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(
                    position);
            Toast.makeText(ct, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("language",
            // arrLanguages[position]));
            // Configuration config = new Configuration();
            String lang = "en";
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                lang = "en";
                break;
            case 1:
                lang = "ar";
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }

            changeLang(lang);
            // getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

            lv.setItemChecked(position, true);

        }

    });
    return view;
}

public void loadLocale() {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = ct.getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs",
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

public void saveLocale(String lang) {
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = ct.getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs",
            Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.commit();
}

public void changeLang(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    ct.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            ct.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}

class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_changelanguage, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_changelanguage,
                parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        textView.setText(values[position]);

        // Change icon based on name
        String s = values[position];

        System.out.println(s);
        if (lv.isItemChecked(position)) {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Ischeck = true;
            SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                    "check", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();
            sedt.putBoolean("Ischeck", Ischeck = true);

            sedt.clear();

            sedt.commit();
        } else {
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        return rowView;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(
        android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null) {
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        ct.getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig,
                ct.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change.

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // get selected items
            String selectedValue = (String) lv.getAdapter().getItem(
                    position);
            Toast.makeText(ct, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra("language",
            // arrLanguages[position]));
            // Configuration config = new Configuration();
            String lang = "" + selectedValue;

            changeLang(lang);
            // getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

            lv.setItemChecked(position, true);

        }

    });
    return view;
}
```